# SQLITE 3 How to Insert include a Custom Function inside a trigger clause Python

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to include a custom function inside a trigger clause in sqlite using python , I'm able to call the custom function when i just call the custom function , however i'm trying to include the custom function inside a trigger clause

This is my custom function creation

```
 self.conn.create_function("autocsvok", 1, self.syslog_autocsv)
```

This is my callback python  function

```
def syslog_autocsv(self,value):
    print value
```

I'm able to call the callback function on

```
   sql2='select autocsvok("ss")'
   self.cur.execute(sql2)
```

This gives me output

```
   ss
```

However , Now I try to include the custom function inside a trigger clause

```
sql3='''CREATE TRIGGER liiasssaa BEFORE INSERT ON syslog BEGIN
            select autocsvok("55") 
            END'''
self.cur.execute(sql3)
print self.cur.fetchone()[0]
```

This gives me the following error

```
File "syslog.py", line 105, in syslog_createfunction
self.cur.execute(sql1)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "END": syntax error
```

Kindly Help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the section of grammar between `BEGIN` and `END`
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

The expression must be terminated with a semicolon. Your trigger's `select` is not terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: mob The trigger gets called now , but  when the trigger function gets executed , it says no such function: autocsvok  , although the function exists